# Angular messes up styling because of selector element

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

A small question. I'v got a bootstrap button group and the buttons are Angular components like the following code.

```
<div class="btn-group float-right" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <app-action
        [actionType]="'invoices'"
        [action]="'send'"
        [buttonIcon]="'fa-envelope'"
        (onLoadingActions)="setLoading($event)"
        [loading]="loading"
        [selectedValues]="selectedActionValues">
      </app-action>
      <app-action
        [actionType]="'invoices'"
        [action]="'delete'"
        [buttonIcon]="'fa-trash-alt'"
        (onLoadingActions)="setLoading($event)"
        [loading]="loading"
        [selectedValues]="selectedActionValues">
      </app-action>
    </div>
```

The action component looks like this:

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn btn-primary" 
  [disabled]="loading">
    <i class="fas {{buttonIcon}}" (click)="onClickAction()"></i>
</button>
```

Because of the  selector the styling of the bootstrap button group is not the same as the normal behaviour because there's an extra container wrapped around the buttons.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What output you are getting now? and what is the expected output? can you show it with images or can create stackbliitz or plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

Except overriding bootstrap style with your own code it's not possible for now, as it's already an open issue : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18877